# Launcher,must have permission android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS

Tags: android

I got some error when run my qpp ,I have no idea of how to solve this question ,would anyone help me please? I run my app at virtual machine,and I have Added the authority

```
11-14 10:09:06.565: E/AndroidRuntime(402): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hskj.iphonehome/com.hskj.iphonehome.Launcher}: java.lang.SecurityException: Access denied to process: 402, must have permission android.permission.SETWALLPAPERHINTS
11-14 10:09:06.565: E/AndroidRuntime(402): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1735)
11-14 10:09:06.565: E/AndroidRuntime(402): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1754)
11-14 10:09:06.565: E/AndroidRuntime(402): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:156)
11-14 10:09:06.565: E/AndroidRuntime(402): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1000)
11-14 10:09:06.565: E/AndroidRuntime(402): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:130)
11-14 10:09:06.565: E/AndroidRuntime(402): at android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)
11-14 10:09:06.565: E/AndroidRuntime(402): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3821)
11-14 10:09:06.565: E/AndroidRuntime(402): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-14 10:09:06.565: E/AndroidRuntime(402): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
11-14 10:09:06.565: E/AndroidRuntime(402): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:969)
11-14 10:09:06.565: E/AndroidRuntime(402): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:727)
11-14 10:09:06.565: E/AndroidRuntime(402): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-14 10:09:06.565: E/AndroidRuntime(402): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Access denied to process: 402, must have permission android.permission.SETWALLPAPERHINTS
11-14 10:09:06.565: E/AndroidRuntime(402): at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1353)
11-14 10:09:06.565: E/AndroidRuntime(402): at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1307)
11-14 10:09:06.565: E/AndroidRuntime(402): at android.app.IWallpaperManager$Stub$Proxy.setDimensionHints(IWallpaperManager.java:343)
11-14 10:09:06.565: E/AndroidRuntime(402): at android.app.WallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(WallpaperManager.java:717)
11-14 10:09:06.565: E/AndroidRuntime(402): at com.hskj.iphonehome.Launcher.setWallpaperDimension(Launcher.java:482)
11-14 10:09:06.565: E/AndroidRuntime(402): at com.hskj.iphonehome.Launcher.onCreate(Launcher.java:322)
11-14 10:09:06.565: E/AndroidRuntime(402): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
11-14 10:09:06.565: E/AndroidRuntime(402): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1699)
11-14 10:09:06.565: E/AndroidRuntime(402): ... 11 more
```

**EDIT:**

this is the key code:

```
private static final int WALLPAPERSCREENSSPAN = 1;
WallpaperManager wpm = (WallpaperManager) getSystemService(WALLPAPER_SERVICE);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

    final int width = display.getWidth();
    final int height = display.getHeight();

    wpm.suggestDesiredDimensions(width * WALLPAPER_SCREENS_SPAN, height);
```

**EDIT2:**

I have added the permission in my app:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS"/>
```

but the error still the same.I 'm wondering if it is caused by simulator,but I'm not sure.Could anyone help me please?the question has bothered me so much.

Thanks all your attention to my question ,I have solve the problem ,there is something wrong in emulator and I reset it all ,so it's solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your stacktrace

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Access denied to process: 402, must have permission android.permission.SETWALLPAPERHINTS
```

You should add permission in manifest. Which is

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS"/>
```

Comment: I have added the permission ,but it still trun out error

Comment: I have update the question with my key code,could you help me please?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS` permission to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS"/>
```

Comment: I have added the permission ,but it still trun out error

Comment: Is it the same error? If not, please post it.

Comment: yes,it's the same error ,I have update the question with my key code ,help me please